# Include all properties of a LESS mixin except for one media query

Tags: css, less

If I have a CSS class that I want to inherit all the properties, except for one property set during a media query, what is the best way to do it?

```
.my-original-class {
    margin: 70px 0 40px 0;
    background-color: @color-gray-light;

@media (min-width: @screen__m) {
    margin: 90px 0 40px 0;
}

@media (min-width: @screen__l) {
    margin: 90px 0;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    padding: 35px 0px;

    @media (min-width: @screen__s) {
        padding: 50px 30px;
    }
}
.my-slightly-different-class {
  border-radius: 50px;
 .my-original-class 
}
```

This is essentially what I have now, but I would like to exclude the margin setting at the @screen_m media query.

Doing

```
.my-slightly-different-class {
 border-radius: 50px;
 .my-original-class
}
@media (min-width: @screen__m) {
.my-slightly-different-class{
    margin: 90px 0 0 0;
   }
}
```

works, but the outputted code doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do it, since it just repeats the @media query over again and overrides the previous selection.

Comment: What is your metric for best? do you mean fastest to compile, most readable? most reusable? shortest?

Comment: You can turn the original class into a parametric mixin and turn its part s on/off depending on a parameter. Though this still will produce significantly more bloated result if compared to just doing `extend` of `.my-original-class` (instead of mixing it) and overriding the unwanted parts (as you do now). Thus, as @Daniel says, it all depends on how you define "the best".

Comment: And can't you do it in opposite? I.e. inherit the bigger class from the lesser one and then add the missing part?